# Change mat-datepicker selected date value according to a time zone

Tags: angular, typescript, timezone, mat-datepicker

In ts. I have used a  **(dateChange)="setToDate($event.value)"** to get selected date.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" readonly = "readonly"  [(ngModel)] = "grid.todate" 
            (dateChange)="setToDate($event.value)" [min]="grid.fromdate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

I want to change that selected date to the server time zone witch is in GMT.

I have tried DatePip.

```
public setToDate(data: any): void {
    const todayDate  = new Date();
    this.todate = data._d;
    const changedDate = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(data.toDate(), 'full', 'GMT');
}
```

The date picker picked the date at 00.00 am. Date pip will not give the time in GMT.

Here's a the example >
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-date-picker-csyldt?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to convert that picked date to any time zone date(with the time it picked)

```
setDate(newdate: string) {
    const _ = moment();
    const date = moment(newdate).add({hours: _.hour(), minutes:_.minute() , seconds:_.second()});
    this.date = date.toDate();
    this.gmtDate = new DatePipe('en-Us').transform(date, 'full', '+530');
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-date-picker-csyldt?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts

I have edited the stackblitz for the ones having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your setDate method like below,

```
setDate(date: string) {
  this.date = date;
  this.gmtDate = new Date(date).toUTCString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment to convert your time to UTC. There is no offset in UTC and GMT.
For date you just pass today date in the function.
var utcDate = new moment("2020-01-24T11:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm").utc();

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best solution was to define the default timezone provider in the *app.module.ts* as follow:

```
{ provide: DATE_PIPE_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE, useValue: 'UTC' },
```

Comment: it's deprecated